# what are some good practices for sight reading sheet music?

Tags: piano, sheet-music, beginner, self-learning, sight-reading

I'm teaching my self to learn the piano, currently I've started learning sheet music. I feel as if I'm not progressing as fast as I'd want and I'm hoping to find some practices to make my sheet music reading more natural. any tips?

Answer (score 2):

After learning the note names in the staffs, lines and spaces - writing down the  note names right in the system, use large lines with large spaces! -  you need to learn the chords and triads, seventh chords, scales and chords in each key, write down the melodies you have in your mind and your memory. By writing the music you have in your mind and playing what you have written, also chords and their inversions  you learn to play what you already know and you will be able to use these chords and motifs  like elements to decipher at first sight new music you haven’t read before. So this is a sight reading and learning to read by writing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any useful 'box-ticking' approach to this.  Just read lots of music.  Preferably get into a situation where you HAVE to read lots of music.  Work with a singer who has charts.  Accompany student instrumentalists in their exam pieces.  If you can stomach religion, play piano for the hymns.  Anything that requires the skill.